# How to mirror my git repository to more notebook at home

Tags: linux, macos, git

How to mirror my git repository to more notebook at home.

My firm is using SVN for version control so I am using "git svn clone" to clone it and then push it to my git repository on the internet. My new question being new to git is how to I get a computer of the repository on my notebook at home

I do the following at work to clone my work SVC

```
cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/
git svn clone http://svn/java mirror.git

cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/mirror.git/
git remote add origin git@git.xxxx.com:MIRROR.git
git push origin master
```

Then I run the following script every hour to push it to the git repository on the internet

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/tmp/svn-mirror/mirror.git/
git svn rebase
git push origin maste
```

Now once I get home. what do I have to do to use the git repository on my notebook.. Please keep in mind I dont know git.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing a simple git clone?

```
git clone git@git.xxx.com:MIRROR.git /directory/in/your/notebook
```

from your notebook?

Comment: then if I make changes what do I do a push master

Comment: If you make changes on your notebook, and want to push to your remote, then do this:

    'git commit -am "my commit"' (commits locally)


    'git push origin master' (pushes the changes to remote)

Please accept my answer if it works for you :)